# Mediawiki Moving Existing images Directory

Tags: php, mediawiki

I have an existing Media Wiki installation. It's a bit older -- currently at version 1.25.1.

We recently ran out of server disk space, so I added a large, storage-only disk that I'm now wanting to move our wiki's images over to. The image directory is easily the largest folder we have, so I was hoping to serve the images from this 2nd drive.

First, I rsync'd all images from `/wiki/images/` to `/symlinkToStorageDrive/images/`.

Second, I updated `LocalSettings.php` like so:

```
$wgUploadPath = "/symlinkToStorageDrive/images";
$wgUploadDirectory = "/symlinkToStorageDrive/images";
```

Now, when I try to view any image in the wiki, I see this error:

```
Error creating thumbnail: File missing
```

However, I can manually browse to any of the images without error, so I know the apache web server is able to serve them as expected. I did try to invalidate the Mediawiki cache, but that did nothing.

I've been stumped on this for hours -- any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: dig in to the code, find the source if "Error creating thumbnail: File missing" see what file path it is looking for.

Comment: @IdontDownVote Not a bad idea; didn't actually think to do that. Let me see what I can find...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is probably just dumb on my part.

The paths used in in `$wgUploadPath` and `$wgUploadDirectory` **must be relative from the Mediawiki install directory**. The reason I previously thought this wasn't the case is because when I had previously used an absolute path from the server root, I saw the image path get resolved to `http://<mydomain>/var/www/html/symlinkToStorageDrive/images`.

Obviously the /var/www/html shouldn't be there, so this made me assume I should define those settings as indicated above -- `$wgUploadPath = "/symlinkToStorageDrive/images";`. Apparently, this is not the case because I finally resolved this by updating the properties like this:

```
$wgUploadPath = "../symlinkToStorageDrive/images";
$wgUploadDirectory = "../symlinkToStorageDrive/images";
```

Note, I also tried

```
$wgUploadPath = "$IP/../symlinkToStorageDrive/images";
```

but this **does not work either**, even though I would have expected that and the final resolution to be equivalent.